# Make fluid move around the edges of an object / mesh

Tags: fluid-simulation

I would really like to have a liquid move on top of the surface of an object. How would I do so?

I thought maybe you have sort of a force field on top of the mesh but I have no clue how to do that in blender.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for fluid [obstacles](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/fluid/types/obstacle.html). To set an object as an obstacle give it "Fluid" from the physics panel and then choose "Obstacle" from the drop down menu.

[image]